# How do I analyze report type of data in Bash?

Tags: bash, text-processing

What is the best way to read the following data in Bash? For example if the data is like a `ls -l` then I could read line by line and I have all the detail of a file within a line. In this case I have data in the following format where each record is separated by empty line. I am just looking for basic idea so I can build my queries for this data.

```
      Source:                 test
      Destination:            test2
      Status:                 Idle
      Progress:               -
      State:                  Source
      Lag:                    16:45:45
      Mirror Timestamp:       Wed Nov  5 21:00:27 PST 2014
      Base Snapshot:          1573980876tsfr10_vol.550
      Current Transfer Type:  -
      Current Transfer Error: -
      Contents:               -
      Last Transfer Type:     -
      Last Transfer Size:     944856 KB
      Last Transfer Duration: 00:01:42
      Last Transfer From:     -

      Source:                 test12
      Destination:            test123
      Status:                 Idle
      Progress:               -
      State:                  Source
      Lag:                    10:41:00
      Mirror Timestamp:       Thu Nov  6 03:05:12 PST 2014
      Base Snapshot:          1573980876prd11_vol.1678
      Current Transfer Type:  -
      Current Transfer Error: -
      Contents:               -
      Last Transfer Type:     -
      Last Transfer Size:     83982000 KB
      Last Transfer Duration: 03:21:38
      Last Transfer From:     -

      Source:                 abcd
      Destination:            xyz
      Status:                 Idle
      Progress:               -
      State:                  Source
      Lag:                    02:40:52
      Mirror Timestamp:       Thu Nov  6 11:05:20 PST 2014
      Base Snapshot:          (1573980876prd12_vol.912
      Current Transfer Type:  -
      Current Transfer Error: -
      Contents:               -
      Last Transfer Type:     -
      Last Transfer Size:     17520680 KB
      Last Transfer Duration: 01:23:56
```

Basically, one option that I can think of that having a loop of 15 since there are 15 values for each record and read through each line and then look for the data that I'm querying, for example if I'm trying to find "transfer size" of source test.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about what your goal is. It sounds like you need a database, but you haven't actually said what you need to do.

Comment: As for me you are able to build query what you want already.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, extract some value for a given Source, or what?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example query. It will be too much of work to import this to database and then do the query. let me know if I need to clarify more.

Comment: Use `awk` and set your record separator to `'\n\n'`

Comment: @Raza according to your example `sed -n '/Source:\s*test/,/^\s*$/{/Transfer Size:/p}`

Comment: @DopeGhoti, even better, set `RS=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gawk`<sup>1</sup> (with glenn jackman's suggested [record separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166487/how-do-i-analyze-report-type-of-data-in-bash/166518#comment273822_166487)):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="" } /\<test\>/ { print $40,$41,$42 }' file
Size: 944856 KB
```

<sub>1. Note: the regex operators `<` and `>` are [Gnu awk specific](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Probably, this perl will be useful: it reads each paragraph into a hash, so you can refer to the fields directly by name:

```
perl -00 -F':\s+|\n' -anE '
    %data = @F; 
    say "last transfer of test = ", $data{"Last Transfer Size"}
        if $data{Source} eq "test";
' file
```

```
last transfer of test = 944856 KB
```

The `-00` option splits the input into records by sequences of blank lines.
The `-F` option sets the field separator to be a newline or a colon followed by whitespace.
The `-n` option makes the script iterate over all the records in the file.
The `-a` option splits the record into fields and stores them in the @F array.

I assume the leading whitespace you show in the question is actually not in your file.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for manual checks, you can use `grep` twice:

- Once for using the right source name (the object). `grep "<source/destination name>" -A 15` will print the object and all of its sub fields (15 lines).
- Second time to find the sub field (object property). `grep "<property name>"`.

Together it'll be, for example:

```
$ cat testfile.txt | grep "abcd" -A 15 | grep "Transfer Size"
Last Transfer Size:      17520680 KB
```

This would be fine for manual checks, but for automated ones we'll need more info. Also DB would be best for this sort of queries.